# How to properly format and write a department/office/lab/subsection of a university?

Tags: university, formatting

How would one properly format a department/office/lab/subsection of a university? If say I work in Lab X of University Y, should I format it like this? 
Lab X, University Y
or
University Y, Lab X? Or something else?

Comment: I have mostly seen Lab, Dept, University.

Comment: What is this for?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of describing affiliations of different authors on a paper "Department name, Faculty Name (optional), Institution name" is common. For example, see this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.06958.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The formatting for nearly any type of addressing is stated ordered from subset to the enclosing superset.

In your case,

> Lab, [Department], Institition, [State/Country]

The State/Country part is seldom included.